# English proverb or idiom

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

I am looking for an English proverb or idiom for the following sentence.

**Talking in the day time spoils one's business ; talking in the
night time spoils one's sleep**

Something like chatting/gossip is a waste of time. But, that just seems to be a phrase rather than proverb or idiom. Kindly help me with the appropriate one.

Comment: Is this an actual proverb in another language (if so, which language, and what is it in the original)? Or did you make it up yourself?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't think it is a proverb per se, but just a sentence that I came across.

Comment: I know it's an idiom/proverb request but if you happen to need some word (perhaps in some other situation) for `unnecessary chattering/gossiping`, `palaver` may be a potential word.  According to Oxford Dictionary, it means "Talk unnecessarily and at length". _e.g._
‘it's too hot for palavering’

Comment: IMO your sentence is quite good on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Proverbs 14:23 {[ISV; BibleHub](http://biblehub.com/proverbs/14-23.htm)} reads:

> In hard work there is always profit, but too much chattering leads to
>   poverty.

A related adage is

> too much talk, and not enough action

More picturesque is

> A chattering bird builds no nest.

(A Cameroonian proverb; the English version happily seems to be catching on.)

{[special dictionary.com](http://www.special-dictionary.com/proverbs/keywords/nest/)}

Comment: That sounds perilously close to something that might end up over a gate…